# Ada: Understanding variable'Size vs type'Size vs value_size vs object_size

Tags: ada

Let the following Ada types be defined:

```
type Type_Huge is array (1 .. Integer'Last) of Float;
type Type_B is (foo, bar, blop, bloub);
type Type_A ( disc : Type_B := foo) is
    record
        case disc is
            when foo =>
                My_int : Integer;
            when bar =>
                huge_data : Type_Huge := (others => 0.0);
            when others =>
                null;
        end case;
    end record;
```

1- Do you confirm the following ?

```
my_var : Type_A;
```

`(Type_A'Size = my_var'Size)` returns `False`

2- what is the real value of `my_var'Size` ?
I would say the size is at least:

```
Type_B'Size + Integer'Size
```

3- What is the value of `Type_A'Size` ?

I would say the size is the max of the possible configurations.

3- Is there anything else the compiler would add (probably hidden) to `my_var`?

I have also read some articles concerning `Value_Size` and `Object_Size`
But I don't get the full picture right now.

Thx

Comment: You should at the very least try this with your compiler; that would give you a data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quoted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872776/40851) the LRM requires `'Size` be defined by the implementation for indefinite types; in addition, [LRM M.2 (45)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-M-2.html#p45) requires that the implementation documents this characteristic:

> (45) The meaning of `Size` for indefinite subtypes.

If your compiler is GNAT, this is what it states in its reference manual:

> Size for an indefinite subtype is the maximum possible size,
>   (...).

You can see the compiler's choice when you add compiler switch `-gnatR3`. The output also lists numbers for `'Value_Size` as they depend on the record discriminant's value. (The (...) part talks about sizes of subprogram parameters.)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting section 13.3 in the LRM:

> (44) For every subtype S:
>
> (45) S'Size [...]
>
> (48) If S is indefinite, the meaning is implementation defined. [...]

In other words: It is implementation defined.